# unable to access the jQuery Object within a plugin

Tags: jquery

I know this sounds pretty trivial, but the following function (`return (`$this).each()...`) seems to be everything but alive in my plugin, which means that I even don't get an alert. Do you have any suggestions for a possible problem?

```
(function($){
    $.fn.plugin = function() {  
        return $(this).each(function(){
            var obj = $(this);
            obj.css('background', 'blue');
            alert(this);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: For testing this, i included a bunch of li elements within a ul-list, selected them and checked the length of the matched elements altogether. The result was always euqal to 0.

console.log($('li').length);

Comment: Wow thx for asking me how i call the plugin...
The solution is quite simple, just as trivial as such a problem.
I forgot to call to include the call into the following:

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li').plugin();
});

Answer (score 1):

How are you calling the plugin? Do you have matching elements? Check the .length on the selector to ensure you have > 0 matched elements.

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){
        $.fn.plugin = function() {  
            return $(this).each(function(){
                    var obj = $(this);
                    obj.css('background', 'blue');
                    $("#result").append('<span>in plugin : '+obj.html()+'</span><br />');
            });
        };
    })(jQuery);

    jQuery(function(){
        var test = $("div").plugin();

        $(test).each(function(){
            $("#result").append('<span>out plugin : '+$(this).html()+'</span><br />');
        });
    });

</script>
<head>
<body>
<div>a</div>
<div>b</div>
<div>d</div>
<div>v</div>
<span id="result"></span>
</body>
</html>
```